# Is there any verbose flag that could cause vCenter db overfilling in ESXi cluster?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

I have SQL Server express installed on vCenter, so the maximum size of the database can be only 4GB. I don't know why, but from some moment the size of the db started to grow exponentially, so I have to delete the data which is older than 40days with the script provided on the vmware site (VCDB shrink sql or so ..)

The question is, is there any verbose/debug flag, which I accidentally enabled time ago, so the DB is filling more rapidly? The VMs count did not change in the past and I did not change anything substantial in the infrastructure.

Or maybe everything is behaving alright and the SQL server should be upgraded ? (40 VMs)

ESXi 4.1 cluster Essentials Plus
Appliances installed vDR, vMA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've surmised, a higher logging level can create quite a large database.

Here's how you check/change your logging level on vCenter.

In the vClient: Administration Menu -> vCenter Settings -> Logging Options.

If offers you a range from None to Trivia (extremely verbose)

NB: VMware does offer a sizing calculator you can use to predict your systems log growth:
http://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/vs_pages/vsp_pubs_esx40_vc40.html

Answer (score 2):

I would check check what are the settings for Statistics in vCenter Settings.If they are changed from default, this could generate a lot of data.
Eventually you will have to bite the bullet and buy the proper SQL , I believe Vmware recommendation is not to use express edition for site with more than 50 vms.